# WHERE IN clause with tuple terrible slow with JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have an endpoint which returns rows given a list of identifiers. The endpoint latency is very high, this is due to the fact that a query is issued for each identifier. A first optimization is simpler: fetch more rows at once. The identifier is a tuple of <identifier_type, identifier_id>. This is the query written with JOOQ (kotlin):

```
fun findBySecurityIds(securityIds: Collection<SecurityId>, fetchBatchSize: Int): 
    List<Instrument> =
    with(INSTRUMENT) {
        val securityIdsRecord: List<Row2<String, String>> =
            securityIds.map { row(it.value, it.type) }.toList()

        dsl.selectFrom(this)
            .where(row(SECURITY_ID, SECURITY_ID_TYPE).`in`(securityIdsRecord))
            .fetchSize(fetchBatchSize)
            .fetchStream()
            .map { it.toDomain() }
            .toList()
}
```

I have my application instrumented with the opentelemetry java agent and it says that the time spent to run this query is more than 1 minute (which ended up to be worse than before)!

I run the same query directly on the db with a random list of 15000 tuples and it returned in around 1 second.

Why there is such a difference with JOOQ?

Comment: *"I run the same query directly on the db with a random list of 15000 tuples and it returned in around 1 second."* - Did you fetch the entire result set, or did you just display the first few rows? Note, some time ago, I made a benchmark comparing `IN` lists with arrays in PostgreSQL (and Oracle), and the general result was that with ~64+ elements, there was a break-even, after which the array always outperformed the `IN` list: https://blog.jooq.org/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster.

Comment: However, running a semi join instead of passing around lists of IDs is always better, so unless you have a user checking checkboxes with security IDs, why not just use the original subquery again, that produced the IDs in the first place.

Comment: Use the autoexplain extension to capture what query is actually sent to the database and how long it is taking.